# Regularity result for the boundary value problem for the heat equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde, regularity

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^N$.

Let $u_0 \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $f \in L^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega).$

Consider the following boundary value problem for the heat equation:
$$
\begin{cases} u_t - \Delta u = f \\
u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0\\
u(0) = u_0
\end{cases}
$$

**Questions:**

- Let $k \ge 2$. Assume $u_0 \in C^k(\bar \Omega)$, $f \in  C^k([0,T) \times\bar \Omega)$ such that $u_0 = \Delta u_0 = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ 
  and assume that $\Omega$ is of class $C^k$. Is it true that there exists a unique solution $u  \in L^\infty((0,T)\times\bar\Omega) \cap C^k([0,T)\times \bar\Omega)$? How can one prove it? Do we need some additional assumptions on $f$?
- Fix $U$ a neighborhood of $x_0 \in \Omega$, and assume that $u_0 \in C^k(U)$, and $f \in C^k([0,T) \times U)$. Is it true that there exists a unique (weak) solution of the heat equation that is regular in $U$, that is $u \in C^k([0,T)\times U) \cap L^\infty$?
- Are the results in the first two questions true even if we assume $\Omega$ Lipschitz? An are they true with less regularity assumptions on $f$?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Do I understand correctly that you are merely interested in the regularity of $u$ on $(0,T) \times \Omega$, and not on $(0,T) \times \overline{\Omega}$? In this case I don't see why the boundary regularity of $\Omega$ (e.g. being Lipschitz or of class $C^k$) should be relevant.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I had a few typos. I'm interested in the boundary regularity as well.

Comment: What are the values of $k$?

Comment: @Andrew Natural numbers.

Comment: Only a small remark on the special case $k=0$: it is shown in the paper "Arendt and Bénilan: Wiener Regularity and Heat Semigroups on Spaces of Continuous Functions (1999)" that the distributional Laplace operator generates a $C_0$-semigroup on the space $C_0(\Omega)$ iff $\Omega$ is Wiener regular (which is for instance fulfilled if $\Omega$ is Lipschitz). Now, one can use the convolution formula for inhomogenious evolution equations to prove continuity results for $u$.

Comment: Concerning your first question, I have difficulties to understand what you mean by "$u_0 = \Delta u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$". Do you rather mean "$u_0 = \Delta u_0 = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$"? If yes, then what is the meaning of $\Delta u_0$ in case that $k = 1$?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I've edited the question to clarify.